# Sequência de datas a partir de um intervalo no R

Tags: r, data

Tenho uma base com ID, data de inicio e data fim.
Queria gerar uma base que cada linha seja um dia dentro do intervalo com uma coluna do ID.
Base:

```
 base <- data.frame( ID = c("A","B","C"),
                    data_inicio = c("2010-01-05", "2010-01-07", "2020-11-30"),
                    data_fim = c("2010-01-07", "2010-01-09", "2020-12-03"))
```

A saída seria:

> ID     DATA
> A     2010-01-05
> A     2020-01-06
> A     2020-01-07
> B     2020-01-07
> B     2020-01-08

etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usando o dplyr e o lubridate você pode utilizar o rowwise que te possibilita trabalhar linha a linha:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

nova_base <- base %>% 
 rowwise() %>%
 do(data.frame(ID = .$ID, DATA = seq(ymd(.$data_inicio), ymd(.$data_fim), by = '1 day')))
```

A função **seq()** pega um valor inicial e um final, calculando assim os valores intermediários.

Saída:

```
  ID       DATA      
  A     2010-01-05
  A     2010-01-06
  A     2010-01-07
  B     2010-01-07
  B     2010-01-08
  B     2010-01-09
  C     2020-11-30
  C     2020-12-01
  C     2020-12-02
  C     2020-12-03
```

Comment: Preciso de uma linha para cada data. A sugestão que colocou me da a diferença de dias entre as variáveis data_inicio e data_fim.

Comment: Fala Rubens, tudo bom? Adicionei uma nova resposta. Realmente eu não havia olhado a saída que você esperava. Abraço!!

Answer (score 4):

Semelhante à [resposta do @lmonferrari](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/483567/117168), mas usando `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(base)  # estabelece como data.table

> base[, .(DATA = seq(as.IDate(data_inicio), as.IDate(data_fim), by = "1 day")), ID]
    ID       DATA
 1:  A 2010-01-05
 2:  A 2010-01-06
 3:  A 2010-01-07
 4:  B 2010-01-07
 5:  B 2010-01-08
 6:  B 2010-01-09
 7:  C 2020-11-30
 8:  C 2020-12-01
 9:  C 2020-12-02
10:  C 2020-12-03
```

Alternativamente, converter primeiro as colunas relevantes:

```
base[, 2:3 := lapply(.SD, as.IDate), .SDcols = 2:3]

base[, .(DATA = seq(data_inicio, data_fim, by = "1 day")), ID]
```

A classe *IDateTime* faz parte do pacote `data.table`; seu uso é similar aos métodos usados pelo `lubridate`.

Veja a ajuda para `data.table::fread` para ver como carregar seus dados diretamente como *data.table* e com as colunas relevantes como *IDate*.

Answer (score 4):

Uma solução em R base poderá ser a seguinte.

```
saida <- apply(base, 1, function(x) {
  x <- unname(x)
  cbind.data.frame(
    ID = x[1],
    DATA = seq(as.Date(x[2]), as.Date(x[3]), by = "1 day")
  )
})
saida <- do.call(rbind, saida)

saida
#   ID       DATA
#1   A 2010-01-05
#2   A 2010-01-06
#3   A 2010-01-07
#4   B 2010-01-07
#5   B 2010-01-08
#6   B 2010-01-09
#7   C 2020-11-30
#8   C 2020-12-01
#9   C 2020-12-02
#10  C 2020-12-03
```